# setting up windows server 2008 r2 to run asp.net

Tags: iis-7, xampp, windows-server-2008

I have a problem when I try to configure my office's windows server 2008 R2

I got the problem when I want to access my asp.net application using local IP address

First (using local IP Address), I set up my application on IIS to run on port 8080 but when I try to access it using local IP Address, it's showing IIS 7.0 page.

any help?

Comment: Are you trying to use IIS as your webserver or Apache? They're pretty much mutually exclusive.

Comment: Actually I was told to do it with IIS and sorry I forgot to explain that I could aceess it using localhost but can't with local ip address

Comment: Then why are you trying to start Apache?  You should take some time and actually *understand* what it is you're doing, instead of just punching in a bunch of commands and hoping things work.

Comment: because as long as I know if you want to access your website with ip address either local or public, you need xampp..that's why I try using xampp..I'm just a newbie after all

Comment: No, no, no. XAMPP is a package that includes Apache, which is another webserver, just like IIS. Again, I recommend for the sake of your company's server you do some research and understand the problem at hand, and the technologies involved. Trying to get multiple (competing!) webservers running (on Windows!) is just *begging* for trouble.

Comment: Okay I got what you want to say...and if using IIS I don't know how to make it accessible using ip address

Comment: Then you should be trying to solve *that particular problem* - which is not about programming, and is off-topic here. You could ask it at SuperUser, but I think if you search the internet you'll find what you're looking for. Good luck.

Comment: ah okay thanks..I'll try to ask there..I have try do some receach through internet but still can't find I'm looking for and that's why I'm asking here